# Huge variations in epoch count for highest generalized accuracy in CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, java

I have written my own basic convolutional neural network in Java as a learning exercise. I am using it to analyze the MIT CBCL face database image set. They are a set of 19x19 pixel greyscale images.

Network specifications are:

Single Convolution Layer with 1 filter:
Filter Size: 4x4.
Stride Size: 1

Single Pooling Layer
2x2 Max Pooling

3 layer MLP(input, 1 hidden and output)
input = 64 neurons
hidden = 15 neurons
output = 2 neurons
learning rate = 0.1

Now I am getting reasonable accuracy(92.85%), but my issue is that it is being achieved at very different points in the epoch count across network runs:

```
Epochs  Training Accuracy   Test Accuracy   Validation Accuracy
```

Run 1   415 93.13   92.44   93.35
Run 2   515 92.44   93.18   92.84
Run 3   327 93.83   92.05   92.38

I am using the Java random class with the same seed for every run to initialize the kernel, the MLP weights and break the input data into 3 sets.(training is being done using the 33-33-33 method)

I am a loss as to what is causing this variation in epoch count to achieve the highest point in validation accuracy. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Was an issue with the random generator. In my class for the Neuron layer where I initialize the weights I get new doubles from the generator for each of the initial weight values, but I found a bug where I was re-initializing the random generator, which was of course causing different values.

Comment: If you feel inspired (and want the rep) it would be helpful if you could elaborate and accept your answer.